Warn users of missing optional permissions in Chrome/Firefox extension
Consider a Chrome extension that dynamically injects content scripts. It specifies "optional_host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"] in the manifest (v3). It only needs the host permission for a URL if the user specified it in settings.
Now suppose the user visits one of the URLs specified in the settings, but the user didn't grant the permission yet. How can the extension warn the user that the optional permission is missing and user need to explicitly grant?
chrome.permissions.request seems to be only effective in user gestures as such a button click handler.

Make the default icon for action in manifest.json to show the extension is disabled and use chrome.webNavigation or chrome.declarativeContent to change the icon on enabled sites as shown in this example with urlPrefix: '' instead of hostPrefix.
